# Problems displaying toast message in update and delete method

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how to put a `Toast` in each of these functions in the following lines:

```
Toast.makeText(OwnerAdapter.this,"Owner sucessfully deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(OwnerAdapter.this,"Owner updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

These functions are inside the `OwnerAdapter` class that serve to create a one-dimensional list of elements. But it's not working because the compiler throws an error:

```
Cannot resolved method 'makeText(com.example.iury.bookapp.OwnerAdapter,java.lang.String, int)
```

- Code Here

```
public class Owner Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OnwerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
// Button update
        holder.button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name_owner = holder.editName_owner.getText().toString();
                String email_owner = holder.editEmail_owner.getText().toString();
                String telephone_owner = holder.editTelephone_owner.getText().toString();
                conexao.UpdateOwner(new Owner(f_owner.getId_owner(),name_onwer,email_owner,telephone_onwer));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(OwnerAdapter.this,"Owner updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((Activity) context).finish();
                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
            }
        });
        // Button delete
        holder.button_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                connection.DeleteOnwer(f_owner.getId_owner());
                owner.remove(position);
                Toast.makeText(OwnerAdapter.this,"Owner sucessfully deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Is DonoAdapter an activity or as the name says a simple adapter class?

Comment: pass activity "context" to show toast.

Comment: @javdromero, Sorry, don't translate completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass context to Toast to make it work.
If the adapter is inside an activity, you need to show a message like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Owner updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

If the adapter is inside a fragment, you need to show a message like

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Owner updated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If the adapter is written as a separate java file, you can do it like

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Owner updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or you could pass context to the adapter and pass that context to Toast

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Owner updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.